# parse all content from HTML and find a string and replace But cannot replace tags string if match

Tags: javascript

I want to parse all content from HTML and find a string and replace But cannot replace tags string if match.

I tried this but it also replace tag content like class name. But I want to replace only text not tag name or something.

```
var toReplace = 'Hello';
var replaceWith ='Thank you';
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(toReplace, replaceWith);
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you're trying to replace say all TD with something new but not all TD that are part of a tag?

Comment: I actually want replace string by a string that find from  HTML Body full content

Comment: So what do you mean not replace tag string ?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<div id="container">
   hello how are you <span class="hello">hello hello how are you</span>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction();">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var re = /(hello)(?![^<]*>|[<>]*<\/)/gm; 
var str = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace(re, 'thank you');
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=res;

}
</script>
```

Try this. :)